# SWIG: How to change the autogenerated "delete_xxx" code

Tags: c++, swig, auto-generate

I have the following declarations in SWIG interface file and a class named **Test** :

```
 %extend qual_name {
 public:
    ~short_name() 
    {
        //Do something here
    };
 }
```

The above declarations generate a **SWIGINTERN void delete_Test(Test* self)** method in the swig generated CPP file. The problem is that I have a lot of classes and the same code gets generated for all **delete_XXX** methods. I want to modify the contents of this **delete_XXX** method for one particular class. How do I do it?

I tried the **%ignore** keyword but that just ignores the whole definition and even removes any calls to it. Not sure if **%typedef** can be used to modify a method content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding the following lines to the interface file:

```
 %ignore qual_name::~short_name;
 %extend Test {  
 public:  
    ~Test() { // custom code here };  
 }
```